# How to solve "Segmentation fault" error in C

Tags: c

I'm not a expert in C, in fact, I hate it, but I have to do this project in this lenguage for my university. Well, when I have gone to test my code, I had a surprise with this error, "Segmentation fault". I was looking for internet and reading people with the same problem and I couldn't solve it.

So, this is my code:

```
typedef struct evento{
    char* tipo; //baja, alta o evento
    char* tema; //tema al que pertenece
    char* valor;
    int puerto;
    struct sockaddr_in *dir;
}evento;

int generar_evento(const char *tema, const char *valor) {

//Socket()

int sock;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sock < 0){
perror("Error en socket() en Editor");
exit(1);
}

//Preparar mensaje

evento evt;
strcpy(evt.tipo, "evento");
strcpy(evt.tema, tema);
strcpy(evt.valor, valor);
```

The code follows but is not important because I was testing it and the error is in:

```
evento evt;
strcpy(evt.tipo, "evento");
strcpy(evt.tema, tema);
strcpy(evt.valor, valor);
```

I need that the `generar_evento`'s parametres (`const char *tema, const char *valor`) be copied in a `struct evento` but when I tried to do it the error appered.

Thanks!

Comment: `evt.tema = strdup(tema)`

Answer (score 0):

```
char* tipo; 
char* tema;
char* valor;
```

Those char* need memory.

Give them some with `malloc(strlen("the string you want to cpy") + 1);`

And don't forget to `free()` them when you don't need them anymore.